# React (CRA) using typescript: webpack can't resolve enum in TSX file but can in a TS file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, create-react-app

I have a Create-React-App application that is in typescript. In this app I have a separate UI library that is an NPM dependency. The UI lib also contains type definitions (models). When running the app via npm start I am getting a compilation error that it can't resolve one of the imports. Here's some sample code:

```
import { PollutantKey } from "my-lib/lib/models/PollutantKey";
```

This can be resolved by VS Code inside a .TSX file or in a .TS file. However, when I try to use that enum inside a .TSX file it results in a webpack compile error that it cannot resolve the path. Importing and using the same enum inside a .TS file (like in a service) compiles without error. Does anyone know the reason for this and a possible solution?

For reference, this is how the Enum definition file looks (generated by Rollup):

```
export declare enum PollutantKey {
    OZONE = "ozone",
    PM25 = "pm25",
    PM10 = "pm10",
    NOX = "nitrogendioxide",
    VOC = "totalvocs",
    METHANE = "methane"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!